# no module cv on jupyter

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I am working on Jupyter Notebook on my windows. I am trying to import module cv and cv2.

import cv 
produces this error.

ImportModuleError: No module cv

Similarly for 
import cv2 
it produces the error :

ImportModuleError: No module cv

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Have you installed `cv2`? It's not part of the standard library, so it won't be there to import unless you have put it there.

Comment: `cv` module doesn't exist in OpenCV 3+, and it's `cv2.cv` anyways for older versions of OpenCV. You should be `import cv2`. If you installed OpenCV into a virtual environment, you have to launch jupyter *in* that virtual environment. E.g. `source activate <your environment>` and then `jupyter notebook` to launch it inside that virtual environment.

Comment: direct link to the candy-store.. just pick a flavor [https://opencv.org/releases.html] here.

Answer (score 1):

To install the opencv-python package without the optional contrib modules into python3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python --user
```

To install the opencv-python package with the optional contrib modules into python3:

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python --user
```

Then to import the module:

```
import cv2
```

For both of these installations, their pypi sites state: 'This version does not support video related functionality for MacOS and Linux'.

The Pyimagesearch website by Adrian Rosebrock has a tutorial on how to download and compile opencv for Ubuntu with this functionality.